# How do I download a YouTube playlist with over 100 videos?

Tags: python-3.x, pytube

Pytube is able to generate a list of up to 100 links to download.  How do I download a YouTube playlist with up to 400 videos?

I am using github code by Mohit23x https://github.com/mohit23x/youtube-playlist-downloader/blob/master/ytdown.py